# get h1 tag within iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe

I'm trying to find an `<h1>` tag within an iframe with an id of `f1`.

Simply trying `$("#f1").find("h1")` returned an empty set.

So I thought maybe it was because the iframe didn't have jquery in it, so I couldn't use those methods.

So I tried a couple of different things. 
Without jquery:

```
var el = document.getElementById;
el.getElementsByTagName("h1");
```

no luck. Sort of doesn't really make sense either since getElementsByTagName is a method of the document. Though I sort of thought maybe an iframe would be a separate document.

Lastly I tried to add jquery

```
var el = document.getElementById("f1")
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js";
el.appendChild(s);
```

which gets jquery appended to the iframe. I can see it in the inspector in the head of the document embedded in the iframe. Yet

```
var el = document.getElementById("f1");
el.find("h1");
```

gets the typeError `Object #<HTMLIFrameElement> has no method 'find`

How can I get the value of my `<h1>` tag?

Comment: @Blazemonger it's on the same domain

Comment: Then [the second answer there](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1639342/901048) should apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the content of the `iframe` is from the same domain as the parent window, you can use `contents()`:

```
$("#f1").contents().find("h1");
```

If the domains are different, you're out of luck as the Same Origin Policy will deny you access.

Comment: TypeError: Object #<HTMLIFrameElement> has no method 'contents'

Comment: You need to call `contents()` on a jQuery selector. From the look of that error message you tried to use it on a native DOM element.

Comment: Right you are. Silly me. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("iframe#f1").contents().find("h1");
```